# Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be open and $z \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$. Can $A \cup \{z\}$ be open?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be open and $z \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$. Can $A \cup \{z\}$ be open?

As a singleton isn't $\{z\}$ immediately closed since the complement is open? Also since $A$ is open the question becomes that when can we have that the union of open and closed set is open? This doesn't seem to be neccessarily true since $[-1,1] \cup (-2,2) = (-2,2)$ is for example open, but we have the condition that $z \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ so $\{z\}$ doesn't share any points with $A$. But isn't it also true that in $\{0,1\}$-topology singletons are clopen? Although I assume we have the standard Euclidean metric here since were in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a punctured ball as $A$ and $z$ the missing point.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard Euclidean metric, we have that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $T_1$ and therefore $\{z\}$ is closed. Now take $A = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{z\}$. Now $A$ is open being the complement of a closed subset and $A \cup \{z\} = \mathbb{R}^2$ which is open.